# A code to repeat my function / keep displaying the text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I would like to display the text in the browser again and again in a new line every time, however there is only the first line of text appearing. How this code should be corrected? Besides, I know that setinterval() is to repeat a function, I'd like to ask how can it be used in this code? Thank you very much!

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text.innerText = create_random_string(20);


function create_random_string(string_length){
  var random_string = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  for (var i, i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
     random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return random_string; 
}

document.write (
  create_random_string(20) + "<br>",
  create_random_string(20) + "<br>",
  create_random_string(20) + "<br>",
  create_random_string(20) + "<br>",
);
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: This will write a new line every 1 second: `setInterval(function () {document.write (create_random_string(20) + "<br>")}, 1000);`

Comment: What is meant by *again and again in a new line every time*?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Once the function starts, there is 20 characters displayed on the browser in one line. I'd like to keep displaying lines of 20 characters on the browser.

Comment: Does that mean clearing the previous line, or adding new lines below previous ones?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Adding new lines below previous ones

Comment: @tenshi's answer might be what youre looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` with `1000` milliseconds. write a random string in a new line every second.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');

setInterval(function(){
  text.innerHTML += create_random_string(20) + '<br>';
}, 1000);


function create_random_string(string_length){
  var random_string = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  for (var i, i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
     random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return random_string; 
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```